# How to identify similar expressions for automatic function extraction?

Tags: compiler-construction, inline, compiler-optimization

How can I identify structurally common subtrees of an AST, in order to factor them out into separate functions?

e.g. given this pseudocode (assume the language allows only pure, terminating functions):

```cs
f(a, b, c) {
    return (a + b) * c * 6;
}

g(x[4], k) {
    var y[4];
    for (i in 0..3)
        y[i] = f(x[i], 1, k);
    return y;
}

varying arr[4];
result = g(arr, 1);
```

...after full specialization and inlining, we'd end up with the following tree of primitive operations representing the program's result value:

```scm
(make-vec4
    (* (arr 0) 6)
    (* (+ (arr 1) 1) 6)
    (* (+ (arr 2) 1) 6)
    (* (+ (arr 3) 1) 6) )
```

(this is a terrible example as the expanded result is still quite similar in structure to the input... assume changes can propagate across the input code's structural boundaries though)

It is obvious to the human eye that the result tree contains three similar expressions, which we could now refactor into calls to a function like `fn(i) { return 6 * (arr[i] + 1); }`, because *instruction cache size mumble mumble etc* (or more realistically to take advantage of e.g. a `map` or `fold` primitive). But how would the compiler identify these as similar, in order to consider them as candidates for extraction?

Eliminating *identical* subexpressions should be easy, using something like hash-consing. But you can't use that for this problem, because the hashes built by moving upwards from the leaves won't be related to each other in any way. Is there a way to "build down" from root nodes and identify a point of divergence between two expression trees, to see where a branch becomes an argument? (*without* using any knowledge of the form of the original program, which has - hypothetically - been expanded beyond all recognition, and anyway might not have been optimally split up)

It feels like there ought to be some way to do this by ordering the subtrees and comparing neighbours, but that would require some kind of element-position-independent ordering...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is called "clone detection".    What you specifically want to do is detect clones over abstract syntax trees.

This technical paper (by me) is (last time I looked) the most referenced paper on how to do this: [Clone Detection Using Abstract Syntax Trees](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/ICSM98.pdf).

There is a commercial tool based on this approach called CloneDR.